# Bad Company 2 conflicts with Y! Messenger

Tags: windows-7, fullscreen, yahoo-messenger

I wanted to post this initially to gaming but a second problem has arisen.

I was using Yahoo Messenger 11 without issues until I installed Bad Company 2, the Steam version. When I installed I was running Y! and everything was fine. I started playing with Y! in the background and every time I received a message or one of those pop-ups with "X has logged in/out" came, the game would switch to windowed mode until I clicked on it again at which point it would go back to full screen.
This wouldn't be the biggest problem, I could simply play with Y! logged off.

After a restart I tried to start Y! and an error came:

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
```

The internet wasn't helpful in this regard, most results were about development.

This was a couple of weeks ago. I reinstalled the system yesterday with the exact scenario repeating. Y! and BC2 worked alongside the first time, with BC2 and its windowed mode issue. After that Y! refuses to start with the same error.

Has anyone gone through this? Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it has something to do with Visual C++ Redistributable. Check out this post: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its/a93d39c3-fd6c-46cd-a547-d5e78782a8ba

Comment: It would be nice [to include the relevant parts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) of the answer here, rather than providing a single link.

Comment: That link doesn't have an answer to it. I uninstalled Visual C++ and it did nothing so I reinstalled Y! and now they seem to be getting along fine, i.e. both work but still with that full screen / windowed bug in case of a popup.

Comment: @bluntkhan Then you should not accept this answer but rather write *your own* and accept it in two days.

Comment: He was the only one that answered and it did suggest to uninstall C++, although I don't know how much good that did. I don't think it's right for me to answer a question of my own.